# ActiveRecord::unknownAttributeError at seeding the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This error pops up when I try to seed my app.

[image]

link to my [repo](https://github.com/Kareem-Emad/TodoLists.git)

What I have done is :
-created  a rails app 
-created four models as described in the schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160823102902) do

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "gender"
    t.integer  "birth_year"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "User_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "todo_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "due_date"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "completed",   default: false
    t.integer  "TodoList_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

  add_index "todo_items", ["TodoList_id"], name: "index_todo_items_on_TodoList_id"

  create_table "todo_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "list_name"
    t.date     "list_due_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "User_id"
  end

  add_index "todo_lists", ["User_id"], name: "index_todo_lists_on_User_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

and I have some relations between the four models that I have created as described in the model file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :todo_lists
    has_many :todo_items,through: :todo_lists,source: :todo_items
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :todo_items , dependent: :destroy
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list
end
```

The error started to arise when I added some data in the seed.rb file as shown

```
User.destroy_all

User.create! [
    {username: "Fiorina" , password_digest: "123"},
    {username: "Trump"   , password_digest: "456"},
    {username: "Carson"  , password_digest: "789"},
    {username: "Clinton" , password_digest: "abc"},     
]
User.find_by!(username: "Fiorina").create_profile(first_name: "Carly"  , last_name: "Fiorina" )
User.find_by!(username: "Trump"  ).create_profile(first_name: "Donald" , last_name: "Trump"   )
User.find_by!(username: "Carson" ).create_profile(first_name: "Ben"    , last_name: "Carson"  )
User.find_by!(username: "Clinton").create_profile(first_name: "Hillary", last_name: "Clinton" )
```

could anyone explain to me what does this error mean , or what I'm supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the column name in the `profiles` table. Its `User_id` but it should actually be `user_id`(Convention over Configuration)

You can solve this by renaming the column(both in `profiles` and `todo_lists`)

```
rails g migration rename_user_id
```

This will generate a new migration file in your `db/migrate` folder. Edit the migration file by adding the following to the  `change` method.

```
rename_column :profiles, :User_id, :user_id
```

You would also want to do the renaming for `User_id` column in`todo_lists` table like

```
rename_column :todo_lists, :User_id, :user_id
```

Comment: didn't work :(  , but now I know where is the problem , could this be solved by recreating the models?

Comment: You don't have to recreate the models. Did you run `rake db:migrate` after editing the migrations? If yes, what error are you getting now? This is the fix I am sure. Rails is looking for a  `user_id` column but you have uppercased it. So, renaming the field should obviously work.

Comment: Yes , I'm sure too that this is the problem , but the error didn't changed , and also the schema haven't changed although it's now  pointing to our migration , maybe I have added the lines wrongly

Comment: class RenameUserId < ActiveRecord::Migration<br/>
  def change             

   rename_column :profiles, :User_id, :user_id

   rename_column :todo_lists, :User_id, :user_id

  end
end

Comment: Did `rake db:migrate` run without any errors? If yes, you should see the renaming done. Open rails console and see if the column_names are changed. In the console, type `Profile.column_names`. It will return an array of column names in the `profiles` table. See if its changed.

Comment: It still uppercase ;_( ,  is there is another way  we could change it manually ?

Comment: Are you sure? If your project's on Github or Bitbucket, can you point me to the repo?

Comment: no problem , I will push it to github right now  ,,and i will provide a link , thank for your patience